# Serializable is sending a null object

Tags: java, android, serialization

This is my code to create the PendingIntent

```
 public PendingIntent checkAlarm(Context context, Alarm alarm) {
        Intent startAlarmArrival = new Intent(context,MyReceiver.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("SerialAlarm",alarm);
        startAlarmArrival.putExtra("CallingAlarm",b);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                ALARM_ID,
                startAlarmArrival,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

This is my receiver

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SettingTime settingTime = new SettingTime();
        Vibrator buzz;
        Toast.makeText(context, "Wake Up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        buzz = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        buzz.vibrate(2000);
        showNotification(context);
        Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
        Bundle b = (Bundle) intent.getBundleExtra("CallingAlarm");
        assert b != null;
        alarm = (Alarm) b.getSerializable("SerialAlarm");
        assert alarm != null;
        settingTime.setAlarm(alarm);
    }
```

I am calling checkAlarm with AlarmManager and am trying to set the same alarm again. SettingTime is an object of my main activity that has the function to call AlarmManager again. Whenever the first alarm goes of however I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

I know the code is not pretty but I want to get it to work before I clean it up but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong

This is my setAlarm method

```
public void setAlarm(Alarm alarm) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        c.setTime(currentDate);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,(alarm.getHour()));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,alarm.getMinute());
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE,c.get(Calendar.DATE));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        days = alarm.getDays();



        if(days[Calendar.MONDAY - 1] && alarm.getStatus()){
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.MONDAY);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),checkAlarm(this,alarm));
            }
        }
        if(days[Calendar.TUESDAY - 1]&& alarm.getStatus()){
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.TUESDAY);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),checkAlarm(this,alarm));

            }
        }
        if(days[Calendar.WEDNESDAY - 1]&& alarm.getStatus()){
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),checkAlarm(this,alarm));
            }
        }
        if(days[Calendar.THURSDAY- 1]&& alarm.getStatus()){
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.THURSDAY);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),checkAlarm(this,alarm));
            }
        }
        if(days[Calendar.FRIDAY- 1]&& alarm.getStatus()){
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),checkAlarm(this,alarm));
            }
        }
        if(days[Calendar.SATURDAY - 1]&& alarm.getStatus()){
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SATURDAY);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),checkAlarm(this,alarm));
            }
        }
        if(days[Calendar.SUNDAY - 1]&& alarm.getStatus()) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),checkAlarm(this,alarm));
           }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Probably you misunderstood. Your `alarm` is not `null`, `settingTime` is `null` here and causing `exception`. Probably you missed to initialize `settingTime` in your receiver

Comment: Where are you intializing `settingTime` ?

Comment: That was the issue, I just had to initialize it in the Receiver function. Now it is giving me an error that ```Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference ``` I am using 'this' for context. Does that not work if it is being called from another activity?

Comment: Please update your code

Comment: There, it is now updated, sorry

Comment: 'I want to get it to work before I clean it up': Classic newbie fallacy. You will never get it to work *until* you clean it up.

Comment: While I agree, it depends on what is considered "clean it up" I guess